How to monorepo with Next.js 15 and React Native (Expo 51)?
So, I followed this example, but with Next.js 15.0.2 and Expo 51.0.38 (CLI generated with Expo router). Also this guide from Expo.
Attempt 1: With PNPM
Next.js runs fine. Had to add node-linker=hoisted in <root>/.npmrc file to make Expo (pnpm run web) runable, but it still does not render pages correctly.

Pages on the left are what they looked like from the stock (expect the blue button, that's shared from packages/ui workspace). Pages on the right are what they looked like when used PNPM or Bun.
Attempt 2: With Bun
Next.js runs fine. But not Expo, same as above.
Attempt 3: With Yarn Berry
Had to add <root>/.yarnrc.yml with:
nodeLinker: node-modules
nmHoistingLimits: workspaces

...then Expo works fine. Now Next.js throws errors with react-native:
Build Error

Failed to compile
../../pkgs/ui/dist/index.js:40:27

Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native'
  38 | // components/button.tsx
  39 | var import_react = __toESM(require("react"));
> 40 | var import_react_native = require("react-native");
     |                           ^
  41 | var import_vector_icons = require("@expo/vector-icons");
  42 | function Button({ text, iconName, onPress, variant = "primary", size = "medium" }) {
  43 |   const buttonStyle = [styles.button, styles[variant], styles[size]];

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./app/page.tsx

I tried adding as below in .npmrc:
node-linker=hoisted

# Nothing works below
public-hoist-pattern[]=*
shamefully-hoist=true

...but still not working.
